# When does a web site become commercial when using creative commons?

Tags: legal, creative-commons

When does a web site become commercial when using creative commons licenses?  I have a free-to-use hobby site that uses a few non-commercial images, avatars etc.

What exactly would it take to cross the line into commercial use?  Charging for use of the site?  Charging for membership that grant additional features?  Donations?

I suppose the question is this, what exactly makes a site commercial?

Answer (score 1):

commercial website is a website, that generates revenue or cash flow of any type that isn't under a non profit organizations filed with that state.

there are 7 different kinds of CC licenses, only 3 of them allow explicitly non-commercial usage: read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license#Types_of_licenses) about licensing types and blocks, which contain any CC license.

Read [CC usage examples](http://creativecommons.org/examples) and this [CC usage How-To](https://www.plagiarismtoday.com/2010/01/12/how-to-correctly-use-creative-commons-works/), so you get more to know about CC.